# Use of the definite article, and different meanings

Tags: definite-articles

1)Study of the methods evaluating evacuation time of passengers from a burning bus

2)Study of the methods evaluating evacuation time of *the* passengers from a burning bus

I'd like to imply that the passengers are from the burning bus, which was mentioned as "a burning bus"

Comment: I don't think it makes any difference. No-one would understand the sentence in any other way.

Comment: That's true, but I'd like to get to the bottom of this, so that I can amp up my understanding of the definite article. Being a non-native speaker, these articles are driving me crazy.

Comment: In this case there are no 'different meanings'. It would also be possible to put another _the_ before _evacuation time_, but that wouldn't change the meaning either. It looks like the title of a research article, so the more concise the better.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this matter. But I can't rate your answer, because it is in the comment section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The presence or absence of *the* before *passengers* (or before *evacuation time*, for that matter) makes no difference to the meaning. The phrase looks like the title of a research article, so the more concisely it's written, the better.

Comment: //Study of methods evaluating evacuation time of passengers from a burning bus// While I agree with you, doesn't it also make sense with no 'the' in it?

Comment: @RamPillai That is what I said - the presence or absence of _the_ makes no difference.